# NSArray/NSDictionary: case insensitive element lookup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsarray, nsdictionary

Is there a way to use `indexOfObject:` of `NSArray` or `objectForKey:` of `NSDictionary` without case sensitive?

So if I have an array:

```
@[@"Apple", @"Banana", @"Peach"]
```

Then

```
[array indexOfObject:@"apple"]
```

can give me 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a lot if extra work and its a bad idea. Case sensitivity is a human idea. When keys in dictionaries are strings (normally they should be) the difference between Apple and apple is a different unichar and a different hash value.

Attempting to do this the hard way would degrade performance .

That said, you might have a valid reason to do it, in which case, you could get the array of all keys, do a containsObject with caseInsensitiveCompare then use the object at index matching. But you might still find nothing.

If your keys are coming from user input or JSON or something, you might do well to sanitize them or otherwise normalize them first.